# Need to Change row to dynamic column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

I have scenario like

```
User | Session | Response
 u1  |   s1    |    r1
 u1  |   s1    |    r2
 u1  |   s2    |    r3
 u2  |   s2    |    r4
 u2  |   s2    |    r5
```

AND the Output needs to be Like

OUT PUT Table

```
User  | Session  | response1  | response2  | Session.....n
u1    |  s1      |   r1       |  r2       
u1    |  s2      |   r3       |  NULL   
u2    |  s2      |   r4       |  r5
```

That Session column may be n time depending upon number responses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement the [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function to perform this transformation of data.  If you have a known number of values, then you can hard-code the query:

```
select *
from 
(
  select [user], session, response, 
    'response'+ cast(row_number() over(partition by [user], session order by response) as varchar(10)) rn
  from yourtable
) src
pivot
(
  max(response)
  for rn in ([response1], [response2])
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c8d69/7)

But if you have an unknown number of responses, then you will want to use dynamic sql:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME('response'+ cast(row_number() over(partition by [user], session order by response) as varchar(10))) 
                    from yourtable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT [user], session, ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
              select [user], session, response, 
                ''response''+ cast(row_number() over(partition by [user], session order by response) as varchar(10)) rn
              from yourtable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(response)
                for rn in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fa1db/1)

Both will produce the same result:

```
| USER | SESSION | RESPONSE1 | RESPONSE2 |
------------------------------------------
|   u1 |      s1 |        r1 |        r2 |
|   u1 |      s2 |        r3 |    (null) |
|   u2 |      s2 |        r4 |        r5 |
```

Comment: This is the script what I need
Really very very Helpfull
Many Thanks

Comment: @user1824559 happy to help, be sure to accept the answer via the checkmark on the left. It will help future visitors and you get reputation from accepting.